# 2011 Dodge avenger

Tags: engine, dodge, avenger

Have a 2011 dodge avenger that has a lifter issue. We repaired that issue we thought so changed oil and filter then took it down the road. Went to get on the highway and as we were accelerating to make the loop back to the house we heard a pop and what looked like a shot of oil and smoke come out the back of the car when that happened the car shut off. Battery was weak and had to jump it off when we started it so maybe that's what made it die when the pop happened? My guess would be the smoke was from the oil hitting the hot block and exhaust because once the car shut off the smoke was gone. I was thinking possibly the rear main seal but wouldn't that cause all the oil to leak out? I checked the oil today after being out of town for a week and it's still pretty much full. I topped it and charging the battery but should I start it or try to locate the problem first. I know if I start it I should see oil coming from somewhere but don't want to mess up anything else.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Unless there was a rear main problem before this endeavor, there wouldn't be one now. The rear main would neither pop nor allow smoke. It starts leaking slow and you only get oil loss and a dirty driveway. You need to figure out where the smoke is coming from. Does your car have the 2.4 I4 or 3.6L V6 engine?

Comment: Has the 2.4! So should I try to start it to locate the leak or try to locate without starting?